# Replace text in Microsoft Word and send back pdf

Tags: java, ms-word

I have to finish a project at my university, which uses Java EE (Servlets, JSP, JSTL). I'm stuck with replacing text in a Microsoft Word document.

Does somebody has any idea or a code example?

Comment: Who is SB? Please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: See http://www.slideshare.net/plutext/document-generation-2012osdcsydney for some approaches